# Reformatting a dataframe to replace repeating similar rows with a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Input.

| Name | Phrase number | Words said |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Phrase 1 | Hi! |
| John | Phrase 2 | How are you? |
| John | Phrase 3 | Is everything okay? |
| Brad | Phrase 1 | Hello! |
| Brad | Phrase 2 | I am good! |
| Brad | Phrase 3 | How are you? |

Desired output.

| Name | Phrase 1 | Phrase 2 | Phrase 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Hi! | How are you? | Is everything okay? |
| Brad | Hello! | I am good! | How are you? |

How would you solve this with Pandas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This page may help you: https://www.freblogg.com/pandas-melt-pivot

Comment: The logic you seem to be trying to implement is to organize sequential phrases by same speaker into sequential columns organized by Phrase Number.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, @itprorh66. This is correct. Also, I know that each speaker will have exactly 3 phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pivot` but have to use a few other methods to clean up the index and columns names (in order to exactly match the desired output):

```
df = (df.pivot(index='Name', columns='Phrase number')
      .droplevel(0, axis=1)
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis('', axis=1))
df
Out[1]: 
   Name Phrase 1      Phrase 2             Phrase 3
0  Brad   Hello!    I am good!         How are you?
1  John      Hi!  How are you?  Is everything okay?
```